# System of 2 linear q-difference equations with singular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I would like to solve the following algebraic linear system of q-difference functional equations:

\begin{cases}
a_{11}\left(x\right)f\left(x\right)+a_{12}\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)=f\left(qx\right)\\
\\
a_{21}\left(x\right)f\left(x\right)+a_{22}\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)=g\left(qx\right)
\end{cases}

where all the functions are $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.
In more detail, the functions $a_{ij}\left(x\right)$ are known (moreover they are analytic and bounded between $0$ and $1$), and the purpose is to determine $f\left(x\right)$ and $g\left(x\right)$.
The parameter $q$ is smaller than $1$.
If we define:

\begin{equation}
A\left(x\right)\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
a_{11}\left(x\right) & a_{12}\left(x\right)\\
a_{21}\left(x\right) & a_{22}\left(x\right)
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}

we have $\det A\left(x\right)\neq0\;\forall x\neq0$ and $\det\left(I-A\left(0\right)\right)\neq0$ (this is due to the special form of the functions $a_{ij}\left(x\right)$ I'm using).
From numerical analysis I know that this system has also non-zero solutions.

**MY APPROACH**

I've tried to solve this problem using the methods developed for q-difference equations (see for example [this link](http://www.uclouvain.be/cps/ucl/doc/math/documents/RAPSEM354.pdf)).
From the system of equations we obtain:

\begin{equation}
\left[\begin{array}{c}
f\left(x\right)\\
g\left(x\right)
\end{array}\right]=A^{-1}\left(x\right)\left[\begin{array}{c}
f\left(qx\right)\\
g\left(qx\right)
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}

therefore if we iterate $n$-times we obtain:

\begin{equation}
\left[\begin{array}{c}
f\left(x\right)\\
g\left(x\right)
\end{array}\right]=\left[\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}A^{-1}\left(q^{i}x\right)\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
f\left(q^{n}x\right)\\
g\left(q^{n}x\right)
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}

where:

\begin{equation}
\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}A^{-1}\left(q^{i}x\right)=A^{-1}\left(x\right)A^{-1}\left(qx\right)\cdots A^{-1}\left(q^{n-1}x\right)
\end{equation}

Thefore in the limit $n\rightarrow\infty$, since $q<1$, we obtain:

\begin{equation}
\left[\begin{array}{c}
f\left(x\right)\\
g\left(x\right)
\end{array}\right]=\left[\prod_{i=0}^{\infty}A^{-1}\left(q^{i}x\right)\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
f\left(0\right)\\
g\left(0\right)
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}

Now, for $x=0$, the system of equations becomes:

\begin{cases}
a_{11}\left(0\right)f\left(0\right)+a_{12}\left(0\right)g\left(0\right)=f\left(0\right)\\
\\
a_{21}\left(0\right)f\left(0\right)+a_{22}\left(0\right)g\left(0\right)=g\left(0\right)
\end{cases}

therefore we obtain:

\begin{equation}
\left[\begin{array}{c}
f\left(0\right)\\
g\left(0\right)
\end{array}\right]=\left[I-A\left(0\right)\right]^{-1}\left[\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}

since $\det\left(I-A\left(0\right)\right)\neq0$ by hypothesis.
Clearly the matrix $\prod_{i=0}^{\infty}A^{-1}\left(q^{i}x\right)$ is singular, since $\det A\left(0\right)=0$ by hypothesis. Therefore we have obtained the indeterminate solution $\left[\begin{array}{c}
f\left(x\right)\\
g\left(x\right)
\end{array}\right]=\infty\cdot0$, which is not good. Since this method doesn't work, do you know how this system can be solved? Maybe there is an alternative approach. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: simplification of the problem**

In order to simplify further the description of this problem, below I write its 1D equivalent case:

\begin{equation}
a\left(x\right)f\left(x\right)=f\left(qx\right)
\end{equation}

where $a\left(x\right)$ is known and such that $a\left(0\right)=0$. So for example we can consider the functional equation $xf\left(x\right)=f\left(qx\right)$. How can I calculate $f\left(x\right)$, given that $f\left(x\right)=0$ for $x\leq0$?

Answer (score 0):

The equation is **not** supposed to hold at $x=0$.

Typically, in such problems you have an **initial condition** which is to be **chosen** and an **equation** which returns you a solution for a **given** initial condition.

For your situation of $q$-difference equations this becomes obvius by looking at the equivalent 1D case, which is

$$ a(x)f(x)=f(qx) $$

where $a(x)\neq 0$. When assuming this equation to hold for $x=0$, we obtain a trivial solution:

$a(0)f(0)=f(0)\Rightarrow f(0)=0\Rightarrow f(x)=0$.

This simplification illustrates that you made no technical mistake, your mistake was asking the equation for the initial conditions.

If it helps, you can think about it in analogy to usual difference equations $a_n=F(a_{n-1})$ where the solution $(a_0,a_1,a_2...)$ depends on $a_0$ (but $a_0$ cannot be determined from it) or usual differential equations $a'(t)=F(a(t))$ where the solution $a(t)$ depends on $a(0)$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand your point, but I think this equation should hold everywhere on the real axis. In particular, numerically I obtain $f\left(x\right)=g\left(x\right)=0$ for $x\leq0$ and positive solutions for $x>0$ (so the functions are not continuous). I think the real problem is the fact that the infinite product of inverse matrices doesn't converge. I would like to find an alternative approach, since the one I have written above doesn't work.

Comment: P.S.: moreover, since the solutions are discontinuous in $x=0$, I cannot say that $\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}f\left(q^{n}x\right)=f\left(0\right)$, so the method I have written is completely wrong. However, as you said, it can be used for q-difference equations with an initial condition, which is a free parameter.

Comment: Yes your limit is not $f(0)$ it is the right-sided limit $f(0+0)$. I think you can just treat the two regions $x\in(-\infty,0)$ and $x\in(0,\infty)$ as two separate $q$-difference equation problems with initial conditions $f(0+0)$ and $f(0-0)$, respectively. So the discontinuity should not be a problem.

Comment: OK, now i get your point, your mistake was assuming $\lim(a(x)^{-n}f(q^n x))\neq \lim(a(x)^{-n})\lim(f(q^n x))$ analogous to $\lim(n/n)\neq\lim(n)\lim(1/n)$, sorry I'm a bit slow tonight ;)

Comment: Hello flonk, after your suggestion about the 1D system, I posted the question [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/154194/a-linear-algebraic-q-difference-equation). As you can see, the problem has been solved, and I think the method can be extended to the original 2D case. So thank you very much!

Comment: @user2983638 no problem, you're welcome!